# DefaultButton in ASP.NET forms

Tags: asp.net, enter, defaultbutton, pressed

What is the best solution of defaultButton and "Enter key pressed" for ASP.NET 2.0-3.5 forms?

Answer (score 4):

Just add the "defaultbutton" attribute to the form and set it to the ID of the button you want to be the default.

```
<form defaultbutton="button1" runat="server">
    <asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server"/>
    <asp:button id="button1" text="Button1" runat="server"/>
</form>
```

NOTE: This only works in ASP.NET 2.0+

Comment: If you want to bind enter key to a a specific area of your form, add an additional `<asp:Panel id="myNewPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="sendEmailButton">your buttons and textboxes</asp:Panel>`

Answer (score 2):

Since form submission on hitting the enter key is a part of life with HTML, you'll have to trap the Enter key using javascript and only allow it to go through when it's valid (such as within textareas).  Check out http://brennan.offwhite.net/blog/2004/08/04/the-single-form-problem-with-aspnet/ for a good explanation.